# camel + netty: send only if remote server is available

Tags: apache-camel, netty

```
<route>
        <from uri="file://inbox?move=.txt"/>
        <to uri="netty:tcp://localhost:5150?encoders=#encoders&amp;sync=false"/>
 </route>
```

I need to send files to a remote legacy tcp server via a socket (IP  and port ). this server is sometimes unavailable   so :

1- I need to check if the remote tcp server(socket ) is  available.
2- if not , i need wait 5 minutes.

I tried several options but none is working.

thanks

Comment: Look at Camel's error handler where you can setup redeliveries with delays in between

Comment: thanks , I added a direct-vm step : <to uri="direct-vm:toTcp?block=true&amp;timeout=10000" />

Answer (score 0):

I made it worked with the following config :

```
        <route id="step1" trace="false">
        <from uri="file:/dev/tmp/datain/?sortBy=file:name;&amp;delete=true&amp;maxMessagesPerPoll=1" />
        <convertBodyTo type="java.lang.String" />
    <to uri="direct-vm:toTcp?block=true&amp;timeout=10000" /> 
    </route>

    <route id="step2" trace="false">
    <from uri="direct-vm:toTcp?block=true&amp;timeout=10000" />
    <to uri="netty4:tcp://localhost:7000?sync=true&amp;textline=true&amp;requestTimeout=50000&amp;synchronous=true" /> 
    </route>
```